# Get Child Node Text in Razor Environment

Tags: jquery, razor

I was wondering how one would be able to get value from child node? I am using razor in the front end and wanted to search everything displayed in the home page.

Razor

```css
<li class="media dotted">
                                            <img class="mr-3" src="~/images/emp-list/mm.png" alt="">
                                            <div class="media-body d-flex">
                                                <div class="text">

                                                    <h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Firstname) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lastname)</h5>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title) (<span class="loc">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.LocationCode)</span>)
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
```

JS

```js
function search() {
            var input = document.getElementsByClassName('mt-0');
            var filter = document.getElementById('employeeSearch').value.toUpperCase();
            // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
            for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                var currentElem = input[i];
                var currentElemChild = input[i].children[0];
                if (currentElemChild.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    currentElem.style.display = "";
                }
                else {
                    currentElem.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('employeeSearch').addEventListener('keyup', search());
```

I looked in the Chrome debugger (figure 1)and can see the value I am trying to search for is in the childnode of the class I am selecting. Not sure how to access it. Appreciate any and all help, thanks. 
[image: figure1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access required childnode value:

```
 `var input = document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
  {
     var currentElem = input[i]; 
     var currentElemChild = input[i].childNodes[0];
     currentElemChild.nodeValue
  }`
```